# What is the meaning of bits 31 and 30 in an SEH exception code?

Tags: windows, seh, exception-code

I'm trying to find out what the bits mean in an SEH exception code. I found out that [bit 28 is reserved by the system for system-defined exceptions from MSDN's article on RaiseException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680552%28VS.85%29.aspx). However, given the exception code `0xC0000005`, I can't discover why it is not `0x00000005`. Is the bit pattern `0xC0000000` indicative of something not lost to the mists of time? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the "Raising Software Exceptions" page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/het71c37.aspx):

> These two bits describe the basic
>   status of the code:
>   11 = error, 00 =
>   success, 01 = informational, 10 =
>   warning.

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks. I should have left the `SEH` off the list of search terms, apparently. Both Google and Bing failed to guess my intentions.